# need some help creating a boot drive

Tags: boot, google-chrome

Im trying to install ubuntu on my laptop, which is a asus x55z, but i am having trouble getting it to boot from the flash drive to install it. the problem is the laptop got messed up for the latest windows 10 update, so i can't create one from it. so i have to use my chrome book to get the files on to a flash drive. i have the file on the flash drive already, but feel like i'm missing something. I have tried changing the boot order, i don't want to mess with too much because i'm not to well informed on the matter. Ha Ha. Any Help on the subject would help.

Comment: have you created a bootable USB drive, and if so how? you say "i have the file on the flash drive already", did you mean files?

Comment: Is there any cloning tool available in your chrome book operating system?

Comment: i just put the .iso file on the USB drive. It sounds like i might be having trouble making it a bootble USB drive. i looked in the chome store to see if there is any apps for making one but didn't find one that could help. I saw on another forum to try chromebook recovery tool, to make one but when i tried it doesn't reconize the .iso file for UBUNTU

Comment: Can you open a terminal window in the chrome book operating system? In that case maybe there is a command `dd` (which we have in linux too). `dd` is very powerful but also dangerous, so you must check and double-check, that everything is correct, before you run the command. Anyway, you can clone from the iso file (when you have it in another drive (for example the internal drive), to the USB flash drive. Check with `which dd`